# Binding Style for DataGrid Cells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles

My problem is simple. I have an datagrid and a bound item colection to it.
The data shows with out any problem, but i want to format the cells.

The item in collection has simply said this structure:

```
{ 
public string Text { get; set; }
public string Title {get;set;}
public Brush BGBrush { get; set; }
public Brush Color { get; set; }
}
```

i mapped it like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Text}" Header="{Binding Path=Title}" Foreground="{Binding Path=Color}" />
```

Data shows, but the foreground and background doesnt change.
Any help will be appreciated.
I may be doing it totally wrong, but i am just learning the datagrid.
Thanks a lot for help

Comment: I think this wont work cause simply Column's Foreground property is not is touch with the data source collection comes from DataGrid's ItemsSource property. And here you want to set each column's cell with a different color not the whole column cells. hope my answer below is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DataGridTemplateColumn` for your case as follows :

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column 1"  Width="150">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate  >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Hope it helps